# How do i playback a .m3u8 file encrypted by AES-128

Tags: encryption, aes, http-live-streaming, chromecast, m3u8

I'm trying to develop a custom receiver application. I used;
https://github.com/googlecast/CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM

My server platform is IIS 7.5, and CORS requirements are satisfied.
In the .m3u8 file, there are two items, URI & initial vector.

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://MY_SERVER_IP/FILE_NAME.key",IV=0x799a4490f82203e21ea413b1bf66bbf8
```

I put the license server URL on the custom receiver, but it does not work.
I get the messages are media player state: "underflow: true", media element state: "Stalled"

How do I solve it?
Thanks for reading my question.

<h.1> Update #1

```
    ######### MEDIA ELEMENT LOAD START mpl.js:58
 [ 38.556s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://serverIP/.m3u8 -1] media_player.js:24
 [ 38.572s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://serverIP.m3u8 -1] media_player.js:24
 [ 38.578s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://serverIP.m3u8 -1] media_player.js:24
 [ 38.619s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://serverIP.m3u8 200] media_player.js:24
 [ 38.695s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0: from undefined to 1308128 media_player.js:24
 [ 38.701s] [cast.player.hls.Playlist] update: http://serverIP.m3u8 media_player.js:24
 [ 38.709s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://serverIP.m3u8 -1] media_player.js:24
 [ 38.719s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://serverIP.m3u8 -1] media_player.js:24
 [ 38.725s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://serverIP.m3u8 -1] media_player.js:24
 [ 38.748s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://serverIP.m3u8 200] media_player.js:24
 [ 38.776s] [cast.player.hls.Parser] unexpected EXT-X-KEY: state 3 media_player.js:24
### HOST ERROR - Fatal Error: code = 0 mpl.js:635
 [ 38.785s] [cast.player.api.Player] unload  media_player.js:24
######### MEDIA ELEMENT STALLED
```

When I try to play using VLC media player, it works.

Comment: P,ease provide the complete console log.

Comment: Media Player State: "underflow:true"; Media Host State: "Fatal Error: code = 0"; Media Protocol: "HLS";

Comment: I guess the problem is that the custom receiver fails to decrypt AES-128. When I try to play the m3u8 media doesn't contain AES-128, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The license file (key) must be served over https.